# How to calculate time complexities for python functions (asymptotic notation)?

Tags: python, big-o, complexity-theory

```
def min_avg_two_slice(A):
    if len(A) == 2: return 0
    n, idx, min_avg = len(A), None, float('inf')
    for i in range(n):
        curr = sum(A[i:i+1])
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            curr += A[j]
            avg = curr / len(A[i:j+1])
            if avg < min_avg:
                idx = i
                min_avg = avg
    return idx
```

Codility has a problem under prefix sums, it's a subsequence with a minimum average slice. The solution above is brute force and was hoping for a quadratic time, however, I got O(N**3) which is cubic.

**Assumption**

1. The inner loop should be == O(N)
2. `curr = sum(A[i:i+1])` == O(N)
3. The outer loop with these other two then become O(N (N + N)) == O(N (2N)) == O(N(N)) == O(N**2)

My question is, was this assumption wrong or there's a missing complexity? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think Assumption 2 is correct; this look O(1) to me.

Comment: Not related to the complexity, but I hope you know that `sum(A[i:i+1])` is actually just a fancy, weird way of saying `A[i]`...

Comment: I would have also guessed `O(N^2)` to be honest, I'd be interested to see where the extra complexity is coming from.

Comment: Instead of `len(A[i:j+1])`, which uses an unnecessary slice, you could just use `(j+1-i)`

Comment: I was about to say what khelwood just did. According to [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) slicing is `O(k)` (`k` the size of the slice) so in worst case (`i=0`, `j=n-1`), it is `O(n)`

Comment: @khelwood I was going to say the same. It spends O(n) time constructing that slice, then just takes the length of it, which is already known.

Comment: Thanks, @khelwood, turns out that's the other complexity I missed. Apparently ```len()``` would've had to loop through the slice, replacing it with ```(j+1-i)``` did the trick. Also, @Tomerikoo, I see that now.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
len(A[i:j+1])
```

you are creating a slice `A[i:j+1]`. Creating a slice is O(n) (where n is the length of the slice). That increases the complexity of your program.

Since you only use the slice for the length, you do not need to create the slice here at all: the length of the slice is `(j+1-i)`, so you can just use that instead.